# Hunter ceiling fan instal

Tags: electrical

I am trying to install a hunter ceiling fan that is controlled by two three way switches. I have two red wires twisted together, two black twisted, and two single white wires and of coarse the grounds. This ceiling fan has a remote box. I have been unable to wire it in to get it working. Any help would be appreciated. And all I need the switched to do is turn the unit on and off.

Comment: If you only need a switch to turn the unit on and off, why are you using a three way at all? You do not want to use a three way if you already have a remote control that is going to adjust speed and possibly light brightness. So step one buy the kind of switch you need/want. If you had a three way, but now need a spst (single pole single throw) switch, then buy those. as for the wires, we will need to know what was hooked up previously and some photos or really good descriptions of what wires you have in the box. Also, please post the Hunter fan instructions or model number, so we can answer u

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: I'm replacing an existing fan with a new one. Old one did not have a remote. The old fan was a hunter model as well. It was wired up with a switch on each side of the room to turn unit on and off. Not sure of exactly how all wires were hooked up, but I do know black and blue wire from fan were tied to one of the single white wires. The fan I am trying to hook up is a hunter model 52258. Have a not very good pic of wiring but not sure how to post it.

Comment: Pictures will help us, you can use imgur, photobucket, or tinypic (.com) for each and then edit your original post and put the link it in. Here is a website that actually shows you quite nicely some of the common wiring way a light is wired. In your case, there is a fan instead of a light. Did the previous fan have light and fan? were they separate? Did your switches control fan and light or was the light only controlled with a pull string? you would like to keep the three way circuit active? But only to make the fan activate? http://www.how-to-wire-it.com/wiring-a-3-way-switch.html

Comment: Does this match your instructions: http://www.hunterfan.com/SupportDocuments/OwnersManuals/M3644-01.pdf

Comment: @MichaelJ See the first image in Ken's answer, which shows how your circuit is wired.  One of the white wires is neutral, while the other is the switched hot.  Use a voltmeter, or non-contact meter to determine which is which (then label the hot with a bit of black marker or electrical tape).

Answer (score 1):

Ok I am going to post something for a 3 way switch wiring - keep in mind if you have a pre-wired ceiling fan box the red wire for a ceiling fan is typically the light kit (attaching to the blue wire of the Light Kit) and the black wire is for the fan.
In the first diagram below the red wire is a traveler wire.

[image: 3Way Switch for a fan]

Take note the fan diagram below is showing a speed switch for the fan and a separate dimmer switch for the light.

[image: Fan Wiring]

Comment: The first image is almost certainly what's going on, except that they've used the black wire as the traveler instead of the white.  In the fan box, one of the white wires is neutral, while the other is the switched hot.  The OP will have to use a voltage meter, to determine which is which (then hopefully label it for future reference).